# Android - UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown failure loading libQt5Core.so

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror, qtcore

This is the first time I decided to write here, but I have long time successfully used stackoverflow, thanks to people who spend his time helping others! :)

Now, I have not found information about this, I am trying to use a library which uses Qt in my android application. The problem is that I am not able to load libQt5Core.so. When running Android throw an *unsatisfiedLinkError: unknown failure*. 
I have tried to load it in two ways.
**First one**, with its own Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Qt5Core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libQt5Core.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES :=  $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
                            $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/QtCore
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Second one**, adding it manually to lib dir.

I load libraries froma Native.java file in this way:

```
System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
System.loadLibrary("Qt5Core");
System.loadLibrary("mysharedlibray");
System.loadLibrary("thewholelibrary");
```

I *mysharedlibrary* with a Makefile, it's the library which uses Qt.
The whole library includes the jni code and mysharedlibrary, I make it using ndk-build.

I have got *libQt5Core.so* from the *Necessitas* package, I suppose I can use it out from the *Necessitas* system.

I also would like make a "standalone shared library" mysharedlibrary with the Qt "inside" it (since I use no Qt at jni in Android" but it does not let me do that.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found one solution:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("Qt5Core");
    } 
    catch( UnsatisfiedLinkError e ) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    }
    System.loadLibrary("mysharedlibray");
    System.loadLibrary("thewholelibrary");
}
```

If your library uses Qt but just inside itself that works.

Comment: are you sure this works for you? I also have an unsatisfiedLinkError but I cannot get rid of it like this...

Answer (score 1):

To load `libQt5Core.so` in your android project, you should add dependency to `QtAndroid-bundled.jar`. You can find the file in the Qt installation directory under the jar directory. After this step you can call `System.loadLibrary("Qt5Core");` without `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

The reason: QtCore's `JNI_OnLoad` loads an activity called `QtNative` when it starts and returns `JNI_ERR` if it is not found. `QtNative` is defined in `QtAndroid-bundled.jar`. I fount anwer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25856689/1091536