# JNI_OnLoad returned bad version (-1)

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, qt5, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to load the Qt5Core library in my Android application and I get this:

```
JNI_OnLoad returned bad version (-1) in /data/data/com.xxx.yyy/lib/libQt5Core.so 0x41a8f3c0
Failed to load library : Qt5Core due to link error unknown failure
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown failure
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
```

This is the way how I'm trying to load it:

> System.loadLibrary(s);

where "s" is an array containing several library names. The other libraries are loaded correctly..

Any ideas are welcome!

---

### EDIT

SO I'm getting this first:

> D/dalvikvm(11445): Trying to load lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.xxx.yyy/libQt5Core.so 0x42666fd8
>   D/dalvikvm(11445): Added shared lib
>   /data/app-lib/com.xxx.yyy/libQt5Core.so 0x42666fd8
>
> E/LibrariesLoader(11445): Failed to load library : Qt5Core due to link
>   error JNI_ERR returned from JNI_OnLoad in
>   "/data/app-lib/com.xxx.yyy/libQt5Core.so"
>
> E/LibrariesLoader(11445): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_ERR
>   returned from JNI_OnLoad in "/data/app-lib/com.xxx.yyy/libQt5Core.so"

...then there is another library which is loaded without any error/warning. That library has Qt5Core.so as dependency.

I have investigated and I'm getting this JNI_ERR because of the following code:

> if (vm->GetEnv(&uenv.venv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
>           return JNI_ERR;

The version of JNI that I'm using is 1.6!!!!

Comment: Where did you get this library?  Perhaps it is not fully compatible with your device, and intentionally returning -1 in the otherwise optional JNI_OnLoad function to indicate that it does not believe it will work.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/downloads -> Qt 5.3.1 for Android (Linux 64-bit, 513 MB)
I think this is the "official" page...

Comment: Unless you can provide meaningful detail about the library itself (source, build process) that people here could use to understand the problem, you probably need to take this up with the QT vendor.

Comment: well I'm just installing QT 5.3.1 for Android and then I'm linking libQt5Core.so in my Android app. I don't have to compile anything because the shared object is already there.
I would provide more details but I don't know what exactly. It's the first time I'm trying to do this :)

Comment: You can try using the ndk's objdump with the -d flag on the library to decompile it, and find the source of the JNI_OnLoad method and see why it might return -1, but it would be far better to trace down the source code.

Comment: thanks but it didn't help. There is no jni_onLoad in there. I was thinking maybe I can skip reading the whole documentation about JNI and anything else that is related to it but it seems I'm not that lucky..

Comment: If you are sure there is no JNI_OnLoad in the .so (try grep on the .so file to make sure) that makes the error message rather inexplicable.  Can you try loading the libraries one by one with explicit calls to System.loadLibrary() for each, and log messages in between indicating which one you are trying?

Comment: you were right, I found this in the .so: if (vm->GetEnv(&uenv.venv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
        return JNI_ERR;  Now the question is why this condition is FALSE because the JNI version that I'm using is 1.6

Answer (score 7):

QtCore's JNI_OnLoad loads an activity called "QtNative" when it starts and returns JNI_ERR if it is not found.

QtNative is defined in "QtAndroid-bundled.jar".  You can find it in your QT 5.3 SDK folder:
    **Qt5/5.3/android_armv7/jar/QtAndroid-bundled.jar**

Just add this to your project's "libs" folder.